# Higher homotopy of wedges of CW-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is $\pi_{k}(\mathbb{S}^n\vee X)$ is isomorphic with $\pi_{k}(X)$, where $k < n$ and $X$ is a finite CW-complex. If yes, could you please give me a reference for such a staff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and a very direct way to see this is as follows.

The sphere $S^n$ has a CW structure with one $0$-cell and one $n$-cell. Since $X$ is a CW-complex it then follows that so is the wedge $S^n\vee X$, and moreover that its $k$-cells for $k<n$ are exactly those of $X$.

Using cellular approximation we can assume that any class $\alpha\in\pi_k(S^n\vee X)$ is represented by a cellular map $\alpha:S^k\rightarrow S^n\vee X$. Write $i:X\hookrightarrow S^n\vee X$ for the canonical inclusion. Then, from the previous comments, the cellular map factors up to $\alpha:S^k\xrightarrow{\tilde\alpha}X\xrightarrow{i} S^n\vee X$. Thus the induced map $i_*:\pi_kX\rightarrow \pi_k(S^n\vee X)$ is a surjection for $k\leq n$.

Finally observe that if $q:S^n\vee X\rightarrow X$ is the pinch map and $\beta\in\pi_kX$ and $F:i_*B\simeq\ast$ is a null-homotopy of the composite $S^k\xrightarrow{\beta} X\xrightarrow{i} S^n\vee X$, then $q\circ F:S^k\times I\rightarrow X$ is a homotopy $(q\circ i)_*\beta=(id_X)_*\beta=\beta\simeq q_*\ast=\ast$. That is $q\circ F$ is a null-homotopy of $\beta$. Thus $i_*:\pi_kX\rightarrow \pi_k(S^n\vee X)$ is injective (this is true for all $k\geq 0$).

We conclude that $\pi_k(S^n\vee X)\cong\pi_kX$ for $k< n$.

Comment: @ Tyrone Thanks for your time and the answer. I really appreciate it. Is there any refrence for such a computation our a general theorem that is above question is a direct corollary of that?

Comment: Well, I pretty much gave a complete and direct proof of the statement. Do you want references for CW complexes and cellular approximation?

Comment: @ Tyrone Thanks! Yes, absolutely your solution is clear and fine. I was just wondering about the existence of a more generalize theorem like Van-Kampen for Higher-dimensional to can deduce my question as a corollary of that.

Comment: The homotoyp fibre of the inclusion $j:X\vee Y\hookrightarrow X\times Y$ is the join $\Omega X\ast \Omega Y$. Moreover $\Omega j$ admits a right homotopy inverse so $\Omega(X\vee Y)\simeq \Omega X\times \Omega Y\times \Omega\Sigma(\Omega X\wedge \Omega Y)$. Now take $Y=S^n$ and argue by connectivity.

Comment: Another way to go is to observe that $X\vee Y$ is the (homotopy) pushout of $X\leftarrow *\rightarrow Y$. If $X$ is $(n-1)$-connected, and $Y$ is $(m-1)$-connected, then the homotopy pushout square is $(n+m-1)$-homotopy cartesian, so you can look to a Mayer-Vietoris sequence to assemble the homotopy of the wedge up to that dimension. A reference for both of the (related) points would be Volic and Munson's book "Cubical Homotopy Theory".

Answer (score 0):

For a CW complex $Z$, denote its $m$-skeleton by $Z^{(m)}$.

As $S^n\times X$ can be constructed from $S^n\vee X$ by attaching cells of dimension at least $n + 1$, we see that for $m \leq n$ we have $(S^n\times X)^{(m)} = (S^n\vee X)^{(m)}$.

Note that $\pi_k(Y) = \pi_k(Y^{(k+1)})$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2226810/39599)). So for $k + 1 \leq n$ (i.e. $k < n$),

\begin{align*}
\pi_k(S^n\vee X) &= \pi_k((S^n\vee X)^{(k+1)})\\ 
&= \pi_k((S^n\times X)^{(k+1)})\\
&= \pi_k(S^n\times X)\\ 
&= \pi_k(S^n)\oplus\pi_k(X)\\ 
&= \pi_k(X).
\end{align*}