# Homotopy classes and CW approximation

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose $X$ is a connected CW  complex with $\dim X = n$ and $Y$ is CW-complex which is $n$-connected. Is it true that the set of homotopy classes of maps $f \colon X \to Y$ is trivial, i.e. $[X,Y]=\{[\text{constant map}]\}$.

A second related question. Suppose $X$ is as above and $Y$ a CW complex. Can I say that
$[X,Y] \cong [X,Y_n]$ (bijection of sets) where $Y_n$ is the $n$-skeleton of $Y$. If not, what goes wrong?

Comment: For the first question, yes by the cellular approximation theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_approximation_theorem. For the second question, no; consider $S^1$ mapping to the disk $D^2$ obtained by gluing a 2-cell to the circle by the identity. It is true that $[X,Y] = [X,Y_{n+1}]$. Think of the $+1$ as accounting for homotopies (crossing with a 1-dimensional interval).

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic Why not an official answer?

Comment: I second @PaulFrost comment

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic : I don't understand what the first question has to do with cellular approximation... To me it's simply by induction on the skeleton of $X$ that you see that at each level the map is nullhomotopic by $n$-connectedness, and then it is globally nullhomotopic as $X$ has dimension $n$. In particular I don't see how you can use cellular approximation, care to explain ?

Comment: @Max Since $Y$ is $n$-connected, you can give it a CW decomposition with one 0-cell and no other cells in dimension $\leq n$. Now any map from $X$ is, by the theorem, homotopic to a map to the $n$-skeleton of $Y$, which is now just a point. I agree that invoking the theorem was unnecessary, as you point out, but it ties the two questions together.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic oh indeed so you also have to find a new CW-decomposition of $Y$, ok; thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(converting above comment to answer; will provide more details if needed)

For the first question, yes by the [cellular approximation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_approximation_theorem). For the second question, no; consider $S^1$ mapping to the disk $D^2$ (obtained by gluing a 2-cell to the circle by the identity on the boundary). It is true that $[X,Y]=[X,Y^{n+1}]$, also by cellular approximation. Think of the $+1$ as accounting for homotopies (crossing with a 1-dimensional interval).

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2226810/39599) for details on the proof of $[X, Y] = [X, Y^{(n+1)}]$.